# Quanto usamos "deva" ou "deve"?

Tags: verbos, conjugações, concordância-verbal

É comum termos dúvidas na conjugação do verbo "dever".

> Exemplos:
> Não sei se é verdade, mas acredito que deve ser.
> ou
> Não sei se é verdade, mas acredito que deva ser.
>
> Ele deve ir hoje.
> ou
> Ele deva ir hoje.

Nesses exemplos qual a forma correta?

Qual regra devemos observar para não errar?

Comment: http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-dever

Comment: Eu sei como *deve* ser, mas não sei o porquê de ser assim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você usa o **DEVE** quando você acha ou tem certeza que algo vai acontecer.
Você usa o **DEVA** para supor que algo aconteça. É obrigatória a utilização do **QUE** antes do **DEVA** no presente do conjuntivo.

> **Exemplos:**

**No presente do conjuntivo:** Acredito **QUE** ele **DEVA** chegar hoje. (Aqui você está supondo.)

**No presente do indicativo:** Ele **DEVE** chegar hoje. (Aqui você está afirmando e/ou "obrigando" que algo aconteça.)

---

Creio **QUE** isso **DEVA** acontecer hoje;

Isso **DEVE** acontecer hoje.

---

Concordo **QUE** ela **DEVA** morrer agora;

Ela **DEVE** morrer agora.

---

Comment: E no primeiro exemplo do Denis?

Comment: ACREDITO que esteja errado, já que com o "Não sei se é verdade" ele está supondo e com o "deve" ele está afirmando.

Comment: Não vou dar +1 porque não fiquei esclarecido.

Comment: Poxa vou colocar uns exemplos...

Comment: Pronto! E sobre o primeiro exemplo dele... Na minha opinião, está errado, não se pode usar o **DEVE** naquele caso.

Comment: No dicionario: [5. Ser provável que.](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/deve)

Comment: - O preço dos bilhetes é 50€? - Não sei se é verdade, mas deve ser

Comment: Mas no caso dele ele utilizou o **QUE**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26198/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-marcos-sartorato).

Comment: Você pode não utilizar **que** com **deva**, eis dois exemplos: "não deva nada a ninguém" e "talvez não deva assumir isso".

Comment: @Armfoot o `deva` de que se fala nesta pergunta é no tempo conjuntivo, e deve-se usar *com* "que". O `deva` dos teus exemplos é no tempo [imperativo](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/dever) (e nesse caso sim, não deve ser usado o "que").

Comment: @ANeves Certo, porém o Marcos apenas referiu "É obrigatória a utilização do QUE antes do DEVA", sem indicação do modo verbal, daí o meu comentário.

Comment: "acredito que deve ser" também está correto, e expõe um maior nível de certeza por parte do orador.

Comment: A gente acha que sabe das coisas mas vai descobrindo cada erro que a gente até assusta o-o Eu estou lendo os comentários e editando a resposta pra ficar mais claro...

Comment: Podes de facto usar o subjuntivo sem *que:* «talvez eu deva lá ir», «não sei se deva lá ir». E *acreditar/crer que* pode vir seguido do indicativo: «acredito que devemos trabalhar para o vem comum», «ele acredita que deve dizer sempre o que pensa». Usei *dever* no sentido de 'ter obrigação moral' em vez de 'ser provável' porque não me sinto à vontade com as frases do 1º exemplo. Eu diria «não sei se é verdade, mas acredito que é/seja» ou «não sei se é verdade, mas deve ser».

Answer (score 0):

*Deva*, parece-me do verbo *dever* e não algum advérbio. Na realidade, sempre substituo por outra palavra que gere menos dúvidas!

Comment: Sérgio, bem-vindo ao site. Quer *deva* quer *deve* são flexões do verbo *dever*; nenhum é advérbio. Se a resposta acima não te esclareceu o assunto completamente, podes fazer um nova pergunta.